# Exception in Windows Phone Store failure log

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

I often see in Windows Phone Store (Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime app) failure log this exception:

```
EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444_Template.exe!{XXXXXXXX-D1A3-49E7-XXXX-316A928B125C}_Task_disconnected_while_still_running:_server_task_currentState_=_Hiding,_targetState_=_Inactive.
```

Stack trace is empty, I can't deal with the exception. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm just checking various crashes on my app and that's one of the errors I'm getting, well very similar: EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444_backgroundTaskHost.exe

Comment: Have you got any reason ?

Comment: Same here, i got this error after i changed the interval of the background task from 15 minutes to a user selected value. after this update of my app i see this bugs. Any info about your case?!